# Automatic PostgreSQL CREATE TABLE and INSERT from CSV or Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, r, postgresql, pandas, psycopg2

Does anyone know of some `Python` package or function that can upload a Pandas `DataFrame` (or simply a `.csv`) to a PostgreSQL table, **even if the table doesn't yet exist**?

(i.e. it runs a CREATE TABLE with the appropriate column names and columns types based on a mapping between the python data types and closest equivalents in PostgreSQL)

In `R`, I use the `ROracle` package which provides a `dbWriteTable` function that does what I've described above. (see docs [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ROracle/ROracle.pdf))

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159841/psycopg2-equivalent-to-r-dbwritetable-command-and-getting-more-performance-from

Comment: The RPostgreSQL package in R also supports `dbWriteTable`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write DataFrame to postgres table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23103962/how-to-write-dataframe-to-postgres-table)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since pandas 0.14, the sql functions also support postgresql (via SQLAlchemy, so all database flavors supported by SQLAlchemy work). So you can simply use `to_sql` to write a pandas DataFrame to a PostgreSQL database:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import psycopg2
engine = create_engine('postgresql://scott:tiger@localhost:5432/mydatabase')

df.to_sql("table_name", engine)
```

See the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#sql-queries

If you have an older version of pandas (< 0.14), see this question:[How to write DataFrame to postgres table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23103962/how-to-write-dataframe-to-postgres-table/23104436#23104436)

Comment: Why do you import psycopg2?

Answer (score 0):

They just made a package for this. https://gist.github.com/catawbasam/3164289 Not sure how well it works.