# How to write DataFrame to postgres table

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, sqlalchemy

There is *DataFrame.to_sql* method, but it works only for mysql, sqlite and oracle databases. I cant pass to this method postgres connection or sqlalchemy engine.

Answer (score 242, accepted):

Starting from pandas 0.14 (released end of May 2014), postgresql is supported. The `sql` module now uses `sqlalchemy` to support different database flavors. You can pass a sqlalchemy engine for a postgresql database (see [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-sql)). E.g.:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql://username:password@localhost:5432/mydatabase')
df.to_sql('table_name', engine)
```

---

You are correct that in pandas up to version 0.13.1 postgresql was not supported. If you need to use an older version of pandas, here is a patched version of `pandas.io.sql`: https://gist.github.com/jorisvandenbossche/10841234.
I wrote this a time ago, so cannot fully guarantee that it always works, buth the basis should be there). If you put that file in your working directory and import it, then you should be able to do (where `con` is a postgresql connection):

```
import sql  # the patched version (file is named sql.py)
sql.write_frame(df, 'table_name', con, flavor='postgresql')
```

Comment: Did this make it to 0.14?

Comment: Yes, and also 0.15 is already released (release candidate). I will update the answer, thanks for asking.

Comment: This post solved the problem for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24189150/pandas-writing-dataframe-to-other-postgresql-schema

Comment: Note: to_sql does not export array types in postgres.

Comment: Instead of creating a new `Sqlalchemy engine`, can I use an existing `Postgres` connection created using `psycopg2.connect()`?

Comment: For writing tables, that is not possible. It needs to be a sqlalchemy engine or connection.

Answer (score 147):

**Faster option:**

The following code will copy your Pandas DF to postgres DB much faster than df.to_sql method and you won't need any intermediate csv file to store the df.

Create an engine based on your DB specifications.

Create a table in your postgres DB that has equal number of columns as the Dataframe (df).

Data in DF will get *inserted* in your postgres table.

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import psycopg2 
import io
```

If you want to replace the table, we can replace it with normal to_sql method using headers from our df and then load the entire big time consuming df into DB.

```py
engine = create_engine(
    'postgresql+psycopg2://username:password@host:port/database')

# Drop old table and create new empty table
df.head(0).to_sql('table_name', engine, if_exists='replace',index=False)

conn = engine.raw_connection()
cur = conn.cursor()
output = io.StringIO()
df.to_csv(output, sep='\t', header=False, index=False)
output.seek(0)
contents = output.getvalue()
cur.copy_from(output, 'table_name', null="") # null values become ''
conn.commit()
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: What does the variable `contents` do? Should this be the one that is written in `copy_from()`?

Comment: @n1000 Yeah just ignore the `contents` variable, everything else should work just fine

Comment: is there a way to replace the table rather than append?

Comment: why do you do `output.seek(0)` ?

Comment: This is so fast that it's funny :D

Comment: Have ran tests for this? Can you post the results

Comment: Load is table is failing for me because of new line characters in some fields. How do I handle this?
df.to_csv(output, sep='\t', header=False, index=False, encoding='utf-8') 
cur.copy_from(output, 'messages', null="") # null values become ''

Comment: What do you do when contents = output.getvalue() throws a memory error???

Comment: @moshevi - The seek method sets the File's current position, so here it is explicitly moving the position back to the beginning of the file, byte 0

https://kite.com/python/docs/StringIO.StringIO.seek

Comment: If you want to use schema, you can add `schema=your_schema` parameter in the `to_sql` part of the code.

Comment: how to specify schema? I got error in python saying that `no schema has been selected to create in`

Comment: For writing the data to a specific schema, since version 2.9 of `psycopg`, you cannot use the `cur.copy_from` method anymore: Changed in version 2.9: the table and fields names are now quoted. If you need to specify a schema-qualified table please use `copy_expert()`. Here is what is looks like with copy_expert: `cur.copy_expert('COPY schema_name.table_name FROM STDIN', output)`

Comment: 3 years later and I land here again ...   ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Load into the PG table is failing because of new line characters in some fields.

Comment: Can we edit the original response cur.copy_from fails. @AlexandreLéonard has the updated call. The original response used to work and no longer does with current psycopg versions.

Comment: Test result: 27 seconds for `.to_sql` (the same for importing csv via DataGrip), 8 seconds for this method. shape = (1,000,000, 3)

Comment: If the primary key is an autogenerated ID this doesn't work as it expects the id to be in the df. Any advice on how to circumvent this limitation? I really need the speed

Comment: If the whole CSV doesn't fit in memory, how would you do this in batches?

Comment: can this approach handle conflicts?

Comment: @Shadi lol. is it still the fastest method still?

Answer (score 52):

**Pandas 0.24.0+ solution**

In Pandas 0.24.0 a new feature was introduced specifically designed for fast writes to Postgres. You can learn more about it here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-sql-method

```
import csv
from io import StringIO

from sqlalchemy import create_engine

def psql_insert_copy(table, conn, keys, data_iter):
    # gets a DBAPI connection that can provide a cursor
    dbapi_conn = conn.connection
    with dbapi_conn.cursor() as cur:
        s_buf = StringIO()
        writer = csv.writer(s_buf)
        writer.writerows(data_iter)
        s_buf.seek(0)

        columns = ', '.join('"{}"'.format(k) for k in keys)
        if table.schema:
            table_name = '{}.{}'.format(table.schema, table.name)
        else:
            table_name = table.name

        sql = 'COPY {} ({}) FROM STDIN WITH CSV'.format(
            table_name, columns)
        cur.copy_expert(sql=sql, file=s_buf)

engine = create_engine('postgresql://myusername:mypassword@myhost:5432/mydatabase')
df.to_sql('table_name', engine, method=psql_insert_copy)
```

Comment: For most of the time, add `method='multi'` option is fast enough. But yes, this `COPY` method is the fastest way right now.

Comment: Is this for csv's only? Can it be used with .xlsx as well? Some notes on what each part of this is doing would be helpful. The first part after the `with` is writing to an in memory buffer. The last part of the `with` is using an SQL statement and taking advantage of copy_expert's speed to bulk load the data. What is the middle part that starts with `columns =` doing?

Comment: This worked very well for me. And could you explain the `keys` arguments in the `psql_insert_copy` function please? How does it get any keys and are the keys just the column names?

Comment: I've tried using this method, however it throws me an error: `Table 'XYZ' already exists`. As far as I understand, it shouldn't create a table, should it?

Comment: @E.Epstein - you can modify the last line to `df.to_sql('table_name', engine, if_exists='replace', method=psql_insert_copy)` - this does create a table in your database.

Comment: @mgoldwasser - I tried what you said with `"append"` instead of `"replace"`, and it throws an error similar to the last: `relation 'XYZ' not found`.

Comment: That's indeed very fast, I still had to use a chunk size for my large dataset (~200k rows) to make this work (it took 6.5s with a `chunksize=10000`). Any idea why they haven't added that function in pandas and only provided it as an example?

Comment: Is this faster than @Aseem 's version?

Comment: You might to add" " around the table name code otherwise it doesn't work with dashes in the table name
`sql = 'COPY "{}" ({}) FROM STDIN WITH CSV'.format(table_name, columns)`

Answer (score 44):

This is how I did it.

It may be faster because it is using `execute_batch`:

```
# df is the dataframe
if len(df) > 0:
    df_columns = list(df)
    # create (col1,col2,...)
    columns = ",".join(df_columns)

    # create VALUES('%s', '%s",...) one '%s' per column
    values = "VALUES({})".format(",".join(["%s" for _ in df_columns])) 

    #create INSERT INTO table (columns) VALUES('%s',...)
    insert_stmt = "INSERT INTO {} ({}) {}".format(table,columns,values)

    cur = conn.cursor()
    psycopg2.extras.execute_batch(cur, insert_stmt, df.values)
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
```

Comment: I get AttributeError: module 'psycopg2' has no attribute 'extras'.    Ah, this needs to be explicitly imported.  import psycopg2.extras

Comment: this function is much faster than the sqlalchemy solution

Comment: This doesn't seem to handle np.nan properly. If you use the code above, you will be likely to see 'NaN' strings instead of Nulls in the database.

Answer (score 2):

Faster way to write a df to a table in a custom schema with/without index:

```
"""
Faster way to write df to table.
Slower way is to use df.to_sql()
"""

from io import StringIO

from pandas import DataFrame
from sqlalchemy.engine.base import Engine


class WriteDfToTableWithIndexMixin:
    @classmethod
    def write_df_to_table_with_index(
            cls,
            df: DataFrame,
            table_name: str,
            schema_name: str,
            engine: Engine
    ):
        """
        Truncate existing table and load df into table.
        Keep each column as string to avoid datatype conflicts.
        """
        df.head(0).to_sql(table_name, engine, if_exists='replace',
                          schema=schema_name, index=True, index_label='id')

        conn = engine.raw_connection()
        cur = conn.cursor()
        output = StringIO()
        df.to_csv(output, sep='\t', header=False,
                  index=True, index_label='id')
        output.seek(0)
        contents = output.getvalue()
        cur.copy_expert(f"COPY {schema_name}.{table_name} FROM STDIN", output)
        conn.commit()


class WriteDfToTableWithoutIndexMixin:
    @classmethod
    def write_df_to_table_without_index(
            cls,
            df: DataFrame,
            table_name: str,
            schema_name: str,
            engine: Engine
    ):
        """
        Truncate existing table and load df into table.
        Keep each column as string to avoid datatype conflicts.
        """
        df.head(0).to_sql(table_name, engine, if_exists='replace',
                          schema=schema_name, index=False)

        conn = engine.raw_connection()
        cur = conn.cursor()
        output = StringIO()
        df.to_csv(output, sep='\t', header=False, index=False)
        output.seek(0)
        contents = output.getvalue()
        cur.copy_expert(f"COPY {schema_name}.{table_name} FROM STDIN", output)
        conn.commit()
```

If you have JSON values in a column in your df then above method will still load all data correctly but the json column will have some weird format. So converting that json column to `::json` may generate error. You have to use `to_sql()` . Add `method=multi` to speed things up and add `chunksize` to prevent your machine from freezing:

```
df.to_sql(table_name, engine, if_exists='replace', schema=schema_name, index=False, method='multi', chunksize=1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

using psycopg2 you can use native sql commands to write data into a postgres table.

```
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='{db}' user='{user}' host='{host}' port='{port}' password='{passwd}'".format(
            user=pg_user,
            passwd=pg_pass,
            host=pg_host,
            port=pg_port,
            db=pg_db))
cur = conn.cursor()    
def insertIntoTable(df, table):
        """
        Using cursor.executemany() to insert the dataframe
        """
        # Create a list of tupples from the dataframe values
        tuples = list(set([tuple(x) for x in df.to_numpy()]))
    
        # Comma-separated dataframe columns
        cols = ','.join(list(df.columns))
        # SQL query to execute
        query = "INSERT INTO %s(%s) VALUES(%%s,%%s,%%s,%%s)" % (
            table, cols)
    
        try:
            cur.executemany(query, tuples)
            conn.commit()

        except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
            print("Error: %s" % error)
            conn.rollback()
            return 1
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Answer (score -1):

**For Python 2.7 and Pandas 0.24.2 and using Psycopg2**

**Psycopg2 Connection Module**

```
def dbConnect (db_parm, username_parm, host_parm, pw_parm):
    # Parse in connection information
    credentials = {'host': host_parm, 'database': db_parm, 'user': username_parm, 'password': pw_parm}
    conn = psycopg2.connect(**credentials)
    conn.autocommit = True  # auto-commit each entry to the database
    conn.cursor_factory = RealDictCursor
    cur = conn.cursor()
    print ("Connected Successfully to DB: " + str(db_parm) + "@" + str(host_parm))
    return conn, cur
```

**Connect to the database**

```
conn, cur = dbConnect(databaseName, dbUser, dbHost, dbPwd)
```

**Assuming dataframe to be present already as df**

```
output = io.BytesIO() # For Python3 use StringIO
df.to_csv(output, sep='\t', header=True, index=False)
output.seek(0) # Required for rewinding the String object
copy_query = "COPY mem_info FROM STDOUT csv DELIMITER '\t' NULL ''  ESCAPE '\\' HEADER "  # Replace your table name in place of mem_info
cur.copy_expert(copy_query, output)
conn.commit()
```

Answer (score -1):

###### Create engine  (where dialect='postgres' or 'mysql', etc..):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine(f'{dialect}://{user_name}@{host}:{port}/{db_name}')
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine) 

with Session() as session:
    df = pd.read_csv(path + f'/{file}') 
    df.to_sql('table_name', con=engine, if_exists='append',index=False)
```

Comment: It works on most database including postgres. You have to specify the dialect in the engine = create_engine(dialect='postgres', etc....)