# Pandas writing dataframe to other postgresql schema

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am trying to write a pandas DataFrame to a PostgreSQL database,
using a schema-qualified table.

I use the following code:

```
import pandas.io.sql as psql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine(r'postgresql://some:user@host/db')

c = engine.connect()
conn = c.connection

df = psql.read_sql("SELECT * FROM xxx", con=conn)    
df.to_sql('a_schema.test', engine)

conn.close()
```

What happens is that pandas writes in schema "public", in a table named 'a_schema.test',
instead of writing in the "test" table in the "a_schema" schema.

How can I instruct pandas to use a schema different than public?

Thanks

Comment: It is not needed to make a connection object with `engine.connect()`, you should just pass the engine to `read_sql`. Furthermore, the function is available in toplevel pandas, so no need to import `psql` for that.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Fixed in my answer.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Update: starting from pandas 0.15, writing to different schema's is supported. Then you will be able to use the `schema` keyword argument:

```
df.to_sql('test', engine, schema='a_schema')
```

---

Writing to different schema's is not yet supported at the moment with the `read_sql` and `to_sql` functions (but an enhancement request has already been filed: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7441).

However, you can get around for now using the object interface with `PandasSQLAlchemy` and providing a custom `MetaData` object:

```
meta = sqlalchemy.MetaData(engine, schema='a_schema')
meta.reflect()
pdsql = pd.io.sql.PandasSQLAlchemy(engine, meta=meta)
pdsql.to_sql(df, 'test')
```

Beware! This interface (`PandasSQLAlchemy`) is not yet really public and will still undergo changes in the next version of pandas, but this is how you can do it for pandas 0.14.

**Update**: `PandasSQLAlchemy` is renamed to `SQLDatabase` in pandas 0.15.

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to specify 'schema' kwarg in meta instantiation. I wrote my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Solved, thanks to joris answer. 
Code was also improved thanks to joris comment, by passing around sqlalchemy engine instead of connection objects.

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData

engine = create_engine(r'postgresql://some:user@host/db')
meta = sqlalchemy.MetaData(engine, schema='a_schema')
meta.reflect(engine, schema='a_schema')
pdsql = pd.io.sql.PandasSQLAlchemy(engine, meta=meta)

df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM xxx", con=engine)    
pdsql.to_sql(df, 'test')
```

Comment: this solution work form me on panda 1.3.5 !