# Pandas to_sql can't write to schema besides 'public' on PostgreSQL

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to write the contents of a data frame to a table in a schema besides the 'public' schema. I followed the pattern described in [Pandas writing dataframe to other postgresql schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24189150/pandas-writing-dataframe-to-other-postgresql-schema):

```
meta = sqlalchemy.MetaData()
engine = create_engine('postgresql://some:user@host/db')
meta = sqlalchemy.MetaData(engine, schema='schema')
meta.reflect(engine, schema='schema')
pdsql = pandas.io.sql.PandasSQLAlchemy(engine, meta=meta)
```

But when I try to write to the table:

```
pdsql.to_sql(df, 'table', if_exists='append')
```

I get the following error:

```
InvalidRequestError: Table 'schema.table' is already defined for this MetaData instance.  Specify 'extend_existing=True' to redefine options and columns on an existing Table object.
```

I also tried adding `extend_existing=True`to the `reflect` call, but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

How can I get pandas to write to this table?

Comment: I recommend posting this as a github issue (I think this is a bug report rather than a usage question?).

Comment: Not really. This is actually not yet supported behaviour (there is already an issue to add this: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7441, I will add this as a usage example), but the workaround I described in the linked question does not work for appending tables in 0.14.1. I will give a new workaround ..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update**: starting from pandas 0.15, writing to different schema's is supported. Then you will be able to use the `schema` keyword argument:

```
df.to_sql('test', engine, schema='a_schema')
```

---

As I said in the linked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24189150/pandas-writing-dataframe-to-other-postgresql-schema/24191432#24191432), writing to different schema's is not yet supported at the moment with the `read_sql` and `to_sql` functions (but an enhancement request has already been filed: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7441).

However, I described a workaround using the object interface. But what I described there only works for adding the table **once**, not for replacing and/or appending the table. So if you just want to add, first delete the existing table and then write again.

If you want to append to the table, below is a little bit more hacky workaround. First redefine `has_table` and `get_table`:

```
def has_table(self, name):
    return self.engine.has_table(name, schema=self.meta.schema)

def get_table(self, table_name):
    if self.meta.schema:
        table_name = self.meta.schema + '.' + table_name
    return self.meta.tables.get(table_name)

pd.io.sql.PandasSQLAlchemy.has_table = has_table
pd.io.sql.PandasSQLAlchemy.get_table = get_table
```

Then create the `PandasSQLAlchemy` object as you did, and write the data:

```
meta = sqlalchemy.MetaData(engine, schema='schema')
meta.reflect()
pdsql = pd.io.sql.PandasSQLAlchemy(engine, meta=meta)
pdsql.to_sql(df, 'table', if_exists='append')
```

This is obviously not the good way to do, but we are working to provide a better API for 0.15. If you want to help, pitch in at https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7441.

Beware! This interface (`PandasSQLAlchemy`) is not yet really public and will still undergo changes in the next version of pandas, but this is how you can do it for pandas 0.14(.1).

**Update**: `PandasSQLAlchemy` is renamed to `SQLDatabase` in pandas 0.15.