# Copy a 8GB txt file into table

Tags: windows, postgresql

I'm trying to copy data from a 8GB txt file into a table in Postgres 13 using Windows 10 psql prompt. The command I'm using is:

```
\copy PERSON1 FROM 'D:\final3\FINAL\FINAL.txt' (DELIMITER('|'));
```

And I'm getting this error:

> Can not stat file «D:/final3/FINAL/FINAL.txt»: value too large

Any idea of how to modify the max size of copy in psql13?

Comment: I do not find that  error message in the Postgres code. I believe this is coming from the OS. Take a look at this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53523051/error-could-not-stat-file-xx-csv-unknown-error)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR: could not stat file "XX.csv": Unknown error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53523051/error-could-not-stat-file-xx-csv-unknown-error)

Answer (score 1):

Add two lines to your txt file: One at the begining and one at the end:

```
COPY PERSON1 FROM STDIN ( DELIMITER '|' );
<here are the lines your txt file already contains>
\.
```

Don't forget another newline after the `\.` line. Then call

```
psql -h *hostname* -d *dbname* -U *username* -f 'D:\final3\FINAL\FINAL.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

I got similar error after new installation of pgAdmin 4 v4. When I returned to Postgres 9.6  in bin\ psql version nothing like that happen.