# psql \copy from program fails with "The syntax of the command is incorrect"

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm trying to import a CSV file into a
Postgres table using the psql \copy from program command.

```
\copy tablename from program 'cmd /c "type file.csv"' with DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

However, this fails with the error message

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
COPY 0
cmd /c "type file.csv": child process exited with exit code 1
```

What's wrong with my syntax?

I have tried to use simply

```
\COPY tablename FROM 'file.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

but this fails with

```
could not stat file "file.csv": Unknown error
```

because the file is larger than 1 GB (see [ERROR: could not stat file "XX.csv": Unknown error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53523051/error-could-not-stat-file-xx-csv-unknown-error)).

I'm using Windows 10 and psql 11.2.

Comment: Try `'cmd /c type "c:\full\path\to\file.csv"'`

Comment: Or wait until PostgreSQL v14, where the problem has been fixed.

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name, moving "type" outside the double quotes and changing slashes to backslashes in the file path did the trick.

Comment: @HannaS I am having same issue but I dont get what you mean for moving type outside the double quotes, do you mind to answer your question or edit it with the command you wrote to try if that helps me. Thanks in advance

Comment: @HannaS I have tried with `\copy table from program 'cmd \c type "c:\data\data.csv"' with DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;` but doesnt seems to be doing nothing.