# pandas.read_sql() is MUCH slower when using SQLAlchemy than pyodbc

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I am trying to read a small table from SQL and I'm looking into switching over to SQLAlchemy from pyodbc to be able to use pd.to_sql()

When I compare the two, the sql alchemy is much slower.

```
s_py = """\
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
cxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL SERVER};SERVER=.\;DATABASE=PPIS;UID=sa;PWD=pwd')
"""

s_alch = """\
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
cxn = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://sa:pwd@./PPIS?driver=SQL+Server")
"""
timeit.timeit('pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM Operators", cxn)',setup=s_py, number=100)
```

Out[21]: 0.18496091418973037

```
timeit.timeit('pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM Operators", cxn)',setup=s_alch, number=100)
```

Out[23]: 4.407356934717654

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29706278/python-pandas-to-sql-with-sqlalchemy-how-to-speed-up-exporting-to-ms-sql) that talks about inserting rows.  But why would the read be so much slower?

Comment: Have you tried using SQL Profiler and/or ODBC traces to see if your two methods produce significantly different results?