# pyodbc to sqlalchemy connection

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc, pandas-to-sql

I am trying to switch a pyodbc connection to sqlalchemy. 
The working pyodbc connection is:

```
import pyodbc
con = 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server};SERVER=server.com\pro;DATABASE=DBase;Trusted_Connection=yes'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(con)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
query = "Select * from table"
cursor.execute(query)
```

I tried:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
dns = 'mssql+pyodbc://server.com\pro/DBase?driver=SQL+Server'
engine = create_engine(dns)
engine.execute('Select * from table').fetchall()
```

Based on: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html

and: [pandas.read_sql() is MUCH slower when using SQLAlchemy than pyodbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48818884/pandas-read-sql-is-much-slower-when-using-sqlalchemy-than-pyodbc)

(trying to setup a connection with Trusted_Connection = Yes)

But I receive the message:

> OperationalError: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('08001', '[08001]
>   [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]No existe el servidor SQL
>   Server o se ha denegado el acceso al mismo. (17) (SQLDriverConnect);
>   [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen
>   (Connect()). (53)') (Background on this error at:
>   http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
>   (Sorry for the spanish but it says that the SQL Server doesn't exist)

I am almost sure that it has to do with me not understanding the sintax for the engine connection. Could someone please explain me in detail how to convert the conection from pyodbc to sqlalchemy?

Thanks in advance!

PD: I am trying to implement sqlalchemy to use later in my code `pandas.DataFrame.to_sql(engine)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I remember having similar issues getting sqlalchemy setup.  I've attached my engine statement syntax.  I don't remember the details, but I do remember the driver selection being a real pain point. I believe I had to download the ODBC 13 driver separately, but can confirm pd.read_sql() and df.to_sql are working like a charm now.

```
driver = 'ODBC+DRIVER+13+for+SQL+Server'
engine_stmt = ("mssql+pyodbc://%s:%s@%s/%s?driver=%s" % (username, password, server, database, driver )
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(engine_stmt)
```

Comment: What is I am using windows authentication instead of a username and password?

Comment: Ah, figured it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085352/how-do-i-connect-to-sql-server-via-sqlalchemy-using-windows-authentication