# Faster solution than executemany to insert multiple rows at once in pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I would like to insert multiple rows with one insert statement.

I tried with

```
params = ((1, 2), (3,4), (5,6))
sql = 'insert into tablename (column_name1, column_name2) values (?, ?)'
cursor.fast_executemany = True
cursor.executemany(sql, params)
```

but it's simple loop on the params with running execute method under the hood.

---

I also tried with creating longer insert statement to be like *INSERT INTO tablename (col1, col2) VALUES (?,?), (?,?)...(?,?)*.

```
def flat_map_list_of_tuples(list_of_tuples):
    return [element for tupl in list_of_tuples for element in tupl])

args_str = ', '.join('(?,?)' for x in params)
sql = 'insert into tablename (column_name1, column_name2) values'
db.cursor.execute(sql_template + args_str, flat_map_list_of_tuples(params))
```

It worked and reduced time of insertion from 10.9s to 6.1.

Is this solution correct? Does  it have some vulnerabilities?

Comment: "but [executemany is a] simple loop on the params with running execute method under the hood" - With pyodbc and `fast_executemany = True` that is not necessarily the case; it depends on the ODBC driver. Which ODBC driver are you using?

Comment: ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this solution correct?

The solution you propose, which is to build a [table value constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) (TVC), is not *incorrect* but it is really not necessary. pyodbc with `fast_executemany=True` and Microsoft's ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server is about as fast as you're going to get short of using `BULK INSERT` or `bcp` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29649340/2144390).

> Does it have some vulnerabilities?

Since you are building a TVC for a parameterized query you are protected from SQL Injection vulnerabilities, but there are still a couple of implementation considerations:

1. A TVC can insert a maximum of 1000 rows at a time.
2. pyodbc executes SQL statements by calling a system stored procedure, and stored procedures in SQL Server can accept a maximum of 2100 parameters, so the number of rows that your TVC can insert is also limited to (number_of_rows * number_of_columns < 2100).

In other words, your TVC approach will be limited to a "chunk size" of 1000 rows or less. The actual calculation is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50706219/2144390).