# SQL Alchemy not_in() subquery hangs the applications, but works separately

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, freeze, notin

I'm using python and SQLAlchemy. The DB is Microsoft's SQL Server.

I have two queries, both rather simple and each involve around half a million of rows:

- subquery: gets a list of IDs from a table. This IDs are meant to be ignored by the other query.
- query: gets rows from a second table. It has several wheres, but the only relevant one is a not_in clause:

```
where(table.c.column.not_in(subquery))
```

The queries are simple SQLAlchemy Select constructs like so:

```
query.Select(table.c.column).where(table.c.column == 'placeholder')
```

Both of them work well when executed separately (and, for the main one, when the not_in() clause is removed), and finish in around 30 seconds.

Here is the problem: when the subquery is run as part of the where clauses of the main query, the app freezes and never finishes executing. I have left it running for over an hour, and it never finished.

It never throws an error, and it never crashes. It simply hangs, forever.

I also tried excracting the results of the subquery into a list, then passing said list to the not_in() function. When I did that, the app crashed. As of yet, I haven't had any luck elucidating why.

I tried reducing the amount of rows returned by the subquery to single one, and it seemed to work. So, the size of the results might be the problem. Is there a more efficient way of handling this operation?

Comment: subquery = db.Select(table.c.id) \
            .where(table.c.alpha== 'a') \
            .where(table.c.beta== 'b') \
            .where(table.c.gamma.in_(('d', 'e'))) \
            .where(table.c.delta== 12345678) \
            .distinct()

I can't really show the table definition. There is nothing special about it though, around a dozen columns that are either string or numeric, only one of which is relevant.

@python_user

Comment: I found out that it breaks when the number of ids to be excluded reaches 2100. Perhaps its related to this issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50689082/to-sql-pyodbc-count-field-incorrect-or-syntax-error

But I tried everything suggested in that thread and nothing worked.