# Bulk insert Pandas Dataframe via SQLalchemy into MS SQL database

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have a dataframe with 300,000 rows and 20 columns with a lot of them containing text. In Excel format this is 30 to 40 MB.

My target is to write this to the database in below 10min. How can I do this?

The question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31997859/bulk-insert-a-pandas-dataframe-using-sqlalchemy). However most of the answers are directed at Postgres databases and the second answer, which might work with MS SQL, involves defining the whole table, which I don't want to do in order to have reusable code. I also checked other questions in the forum without success.

I have the following three requirements:

- Use a Pandas Dataframe
- Use SQLalchemy for the database connection
- Write to a MS SQL database

From experimenting I found a solution that takes 5 to 6 hours to complete. I provide some code below where you can test my current solution with dummy data. The only thing that needs to be replaced is the url_object.

```
#For database connection to INFOR LN database
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL
#To be able to use dataframes for data transformation
import pandas as pd
#Used for progress bar functionality
from tqdm import tqdm
#For reading JSON files
import json
#For random dataframe creation
import random
import string


content = open('config.json')
config = json.load(content)
db_user = config['user']
db_password = config['password']

url_object = URL.create(
    "mssql+pyodbc"
    , username=db_user
    , password=db_password
    , host="Server_Name"
    , database="Database"
    , query={"driver": "SQL Server Native Client 11.0"}
)


#Thank you chat GPT. 

# Set random seed for reproducibility
random.seed(42)

# Generate random numbers between 0 and 1000000 for 5 columns
num_cols = ['num_col1', 'num_col2', 'num_col3', 'num_col4', 'num_col5']
data = {
    col: [random.randint(0, 1000000) for _ in range(50000)] for col in num_cols
}

# Generate random texts with less than 50 characters for 15 columns
text_cols = ['text_col1', 'text_col2', 'text_col3', 'text_col4', 'text_col5',
             'text_col6', 'text_col7', 'text_col8', 'text_col9', 'text_col10',
             'text_col11', 'text_col12', 'text_col13', 'text_col14', 'text_col15']
for col in text_cols:
    data[col] = [''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, k=random.randint(1, 50)))
                 for _ in range(50000)]

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)



engine = create_engine(url_object, fast_executemany=True)

df["Python_Script_Excecution_Timestamp"] = pd.Timestamp('now')

def chunker(seq, size):
    # from http://stackoverflow.com/a/434328
    return (seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in range(0, len(seq), size))

def insert_with_progress(df):

    chunksize = 50
    with tqdm(total=len(df)) as pbar:
        for i, cdf in enumerate(chunker(df, chunksize)):
            replace = "replace" if i == 0 else "append"
            cdf.to_sql("Testtable"
                    , engine
                    , schema="dbo"
                    , if_exists=replace
                    , index=False
                    , chunksize = 50
                    , method='multi'
                   )
            pbar.update(chunksize)
            
insert_with_progress(df)
```

In my specific case I can't increase the chunk size because of an error that get's thrown if I do. Explanation is that MS SQL doesn't allow for more than 2100 parameters per insert. Explanation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50689082/to-sql-pyodbc-count-field-incorrect-or-syntax-error).

> Error: ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question and the answer from Gord Thompson helped :D

[to_sql pyodbc count field incorrect or syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50689082/to-sql-pyodbc-count-field-incorrect-or-syntax-error)

Code is also super simple.
Loads in 6min now.

```
engine = create_engine(url_object, fast_executemany=True)

df.to_sql("Testtable"
          , engine
          , schema="dbo"
          , index=False
          , if_exists="replace"
         )
```