# Need advice for python pandas using pyodbc to_sql to sqlserver extremely slow

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing incorrect in writing rows to a SQL Server using python 3.11.4, pyodbc 4.0.39, sqlalchemy 2.0.20.  The problem is that about 100k rows takes nearly a day and a half to insert into a table.  The table does not have any indexes and is empty.  I'm hoping the snippet of code provide some insight.

```
cn_1 = sa.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://servername/dbname?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server', fast_executemany=True)

df.to_sql(
    "mytable",
    cn_1,
    if_exists="replace",
    index=False,
)
```

Comment: Try adding the parameter `method='multi'` to the call to `to_sql()`

Comment: You might also want to `cn_1 = sa.create_engine(...).connect()`

Comment: How many columns are there in the DataFrame? Also, does the first row of the DataFrame contain any `None` or `NaN` values?

Comment: `method="multi"` is not the best choice for `mssql+pyodbc://`. Details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50706219/2144390).

Answer (score 0):

`to_sql` function doesn't perform bulk insertion by default. To improve performance, you can try using the `method='multi'` parameter in the to_sql function, which uses the executemany method for bulk insertion.

```
df.to_sql(
     "mytable",
      cn_1,
      if_exists="replace",
      index=False,
      method='multi'
)
```

Another reason for slow performance can be `network latency`, `server performance` ,  `driver configuration`

Comment: You are mistaken. `.to_sql(method=None)` (the default) results in `.executemany()` calls at the DBAPI (e.g., pyodbc) layer. `.to_sql(method="multi")` constructs a multi-row INSERT which is passed to `.execute()`, not `.executemany()`. For pyodbc, `.executemany()` with `fast_executemany=True` is almost always faster than `.to_sql(method="multi")`. Details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50706219/2144390).

Comment: Thanks to all that have answered.    Gord,  I have been reading through stack overflow and appreciate your knowledge and insight and wish I could send you directly a question but i guess it's not how stackoverflow works.  So I will try to answer the questions you've asked.     Yes likely there are null values in first row.  Anything that should be done as a result?  So what I am gathering is using multi is not best for sql server...  but should i use chunk size to keep it fast?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct for most cases. However, there is a known issue with `fast_executemany=True` when working with a DataFrame that contains a lot of `None` or `NaN` values:

https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/741

One possible workaround would be to use [this](https://gist.github.com/gordthompson/1fb0f1c3f5edbf6192e596de8350f205) as the `method=` for `.to_sql()`, e.g.,

```py
from mssql_insert_json import mssql_insert_json

# …

cn_1 = sa.create_engine(
    'mssql+pyodbc://servername/dbname?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server',
    # `fast_executemany=True` is not required
)

df.to_sql(
    "mytable",
    cn_1,
    if_exists="replace",
    index=False,
    method=mssql_insert_json
)
```

Comment: I think you might have just pushed against my ability boundaries.  I read the link above but got lost in transitioning to Json.  The above snippet is clear, but do I need to do anything to convert the data to Json?  Thanks!

Comment: The `mssql_insert_json` function takes care of that for you. pandas provides the column names as `keys` and the values as `data_iter`. The function creates a list of dict (JSON) with `json_data = [dict(zip(keys, row)) for row in data_iter]` and then converts it to a string with `json.dumps(json_data, default=str)`

Comment: I have dug in to figure out mssql_insert_jason and have made some progress.  However, it failed I think because the routine can't handle a BOOLEAN datatype.  I get the following error:  sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Column, parameter, or variable #1: Cannot find data type BOOLEAN.   Thoughts?

Comment: That's a bug. I have updated [the gist](https://gist.github.com/gordthompson/1fb0f1c3f5edbf6192e596de8350f205). Please try again.

Comment: Your change fixed the boolean issue! Thanks.... Next error I got was   cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
pyodbc.DataError: ('22007', '[22007] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. (241) (SQLParamData)')   Tomorrow I will ensure all datetime fields seem to be accurate.   More to follow...  thanks very much for your help and ideas!

Comment: I jumped back on and made sure all dates in dataframe where converted to datetimes so it must be a valid datetime that does not get translated correctly.  I still get same error.  Ideas?

Comment: I have updated the [gist](https://gist.github.com/gordthompson/1fb0f1c3f5edbf6192e596de8350f205) again. It now specifies `datetime2` for date/time columns with `OPENJSON()`.

Comment: That worked!  Thank you for your help!  I will now try to implement in actual code.  With the mssql_insert_json method/function can i use replace if_exists="append" to if_exists="replace" so that if table exists it will replace it?

Comment: Nevermind on last question.... Thanks for all your help!