# Insert Information to MySQL from multiple related excel files

Tags: python, mysql, sql, excel, database

So i have this huge DB schema from a vehicle board cards, this data is actually stored in multiple excel files, my job was to create a database scheema to dump all this data into a MySql, but now i need to create the process to insert data into the DB.

This is an example of how is the excel tables sorted:
[image: Excel Data example]

The thing is that all this excel files are not well tagged.
My question is, what do i need to do in order to create a script to dump all this data from the excel to the DB?
I'm also using ids, Foreign keys, Primary Keys, joins, etc.

[image]

I've thought about this so far:

1.-Normalize the structure of the tables in Excel in a good way so that data can be inserted with SQL language.

2.-Create a script in python to insert the data of each table.

Can you help out where should i start and how? what topics i should google?

Comment: I'd write a little VBA macro to export to delimited files, then read into MySQL with whatever tool you want.

Answer (score 0):

With pandas you can easily read from excel (both csv and xlsx) and dump the data into any database

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')
df.to_sql(sql_table)
```

If you have performance issues dumping to MySQL, you can find another way of doing the dump here
[python pandas to_sql with sqlalchemy : how to speed up exporting to MS SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29706278/python-pandas-to-sql-with-sqlalchemy-how-to-speed-up-exporting-to-ms-sql)