# Writing to PostgreSQL from pandas: AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'cursor'

Tags: postgresql, pandas, sqlalchemy, ipython, jupyter

I am trying to write a table to a PostgreSQL database from a Pandas data frame (following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23103962/how-to-write-dataframe-to-postgres-table) answer) but I am getting the error `AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'cursor'`

My code is:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(1, 11), 
                  data=np.random.random(size=(10, 10)),
                  columns=['c{}'.format(i) for i in np.arange(1, 11)])

engine = create_engine('postgresql://user@localhost:5432/db')
df.to_sql('scores', engine)
```

`engine` can connect to the db and return table names.

I am using Python 2.7.8, Pandas 0.15.2, Sqlalchmey 1.0.10 and Postgre 9.4.5.0

---- EDIT ----

I should add that I was getting the error when running this code from within a Jupyter notebook (iPython 3.0.0). When I run from a Python command line it works fine.

---- Full traceback ----

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-276-da2dfbe48036> in <module>()
      8 
      9 engine = create_engine('postgresql://phil@localhost:5432/rh')
---> 10 df.to_sql('scores', con=engine)

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in to_sql(self, name, con, flavor, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype)
    964             self, name, con, flavor=flavor, schema=schema, if_exists=if_exists,
    965             index=index, index_label=index_label, chunksize=chunksize,
--> 966             dtype=dtype)
    967 
    968     def to_pickle(self, path):

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.pyc in to_sql(frame, name, con, flavor, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype)
    536     pandas_sql.to_sql(frame, name, if_exists=if_exists, index=index,
    537                       index_label=index_label, schema=schema,
--> 538                       chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)
    539 
    540 

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.pyc in to_sql(self, frame, name, if_exists, index, index_label, schema, chunksize, dtype)
   1502                             if_exists=if_exists, index_label=index_label,
   1503                             dtype=dtype)
-> 1504         table.create()
   1505         table.insert(chunksize)
   1506 

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.pyc in create(self)
    635 
    636     def create(self):
--> 637         if self.exists():
    638             if self.if_exists == 'fail':
    639                 raise ValueError("Table '%s' already exists." % self.name)

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.pyc in exists(self)
    623 
    624     def exists(self):
--> 625         return self.pd_sql.has_table(self.name, self.schema)
    626 
    627     def sql_schema(self):

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.pyc in has_table(self, name, schema)
   1512         query = flavor_map.get(self.flavor)
   1513 
-> 1514         return len(self.execute(query).fetchall()) > 0
   1515 
   1516     def get_table(self, table_name, schema=None):

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.pyc in execute(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1403             cur = self.con
   1404         else:
-> 1405             cur = self.con.cursor()
   1406         try:
   1407             if kwargs:

AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'cursor'
```

Comment: what version of `psycopg2` are you using?

Comment: Does this need `psycopg2`? Anyway I am running 2.6.1

Comment: This may be an iPython issue as I am running from a notebook - when I run from the Python command line it works OK

Comment: it also works for me from the python interpreter, though it also works in jupyter. can you edit the question to describe exactly how you're running this?

Comment: Can you check your pandas version again? By printing `pd.__version__` both in the notebook as in the python command line. It is possible that it is picking a different version (the error you see could be explained by having an older pandas version)

Comment: @joris Jupyter and command line both using Pandas 0.15.2

Comment: Can you show the full traceback of the error to see from where it is coming? The only reason I can imagine that this error turns up is because the legacy code path is taken for some reason.

Comment: @joris full traceback added

Comment: Can you show the output of `isinstance(con, sqlalchemy.engine.Engine)` in the same environment as where you get the error?

Comment: Any updates on this one?