# import big csv with lots of columns into postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, csv

I have a csv file with 2550 columns and I want to import it into postgreSQL.

For importing csv in postgreSQL at first I should create the table and them use `\copy` to copy from csv to table. but what if the table has huge amount of columns like my case that I cannot create table manually.

any solution?

**Update**

Data structure is as following:
dZ(01) till dZ(2550) are basically between -50 to +50:

```
id | date    | time      | localtime | pid | dZ(0)..dZ(1)......dZ(2550)|
---|---------|-----------|-----------|-----|---------------------------|
17|11-11-2014| 16:33:21 | 1.45E+15   |2375 |0 0 0 0 0 -1 0 -1 0 -5 -10|
```

CSV structure: (I used '';' delimiter)

```
17;13-11-2014;08:09:37;1.45E+15;4098;0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -4 3 0 -2 3 -2 1 0 0 1 1 3 -2 3 4 2 -2 -2 ....
```

This is one line of data.

Comment: I'm afraid you are limited to 1600 columns in table, so you probably will ned to try setting up custom delimiter and import the whole line as one column, so later you could select `split_part` or regex into several columns. but anyway you wont be able to import all 2550 to same table

Comment: How large is each individual line? Maybe you could import it into a table with only one `text` column and process it in the database. A table with that many columns doesn't make much sense in a relational database.

Comment: Looks like repeating group. Maybe store it into an array? BTW: date+time should be one (timestamp) field.

Comment: You could use the [file_textarray_fdw](https://pgxn.org/dist/file_textarray_fdw/) foreign data wrapper which maps the line of a CSV file to a single array in Postgres. You can then use the Postgres array functions to split the table or get a subset of the "columns"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import the `dZ` column into a text column and later turn it into an array:

Create the temporary table:

```
create table s (
    id int,
    date date,
    time time,
    localt double precision,
    pid int,
    dz text
);
```

Set the date style:

```
set datestyle = 'DMY';
```

Import into the temporary table;

```
\copy s from '/home/cpn/codigo/file.csv' with (format csv, delimiter ';')
```

Create the definitive table merging date and time into a timestamp and turning `dZ` into an array:

```
create table t (
    id int,
    datetime timestamp,
    localt double precision,
    pid int,
    dz integer[]
);
```

Populate the definitive from the temporary:

```
insert into t (id, datetime, localt, pid, dz)
select
    id, date + time, localt, pid,
    regexp_split_to_array(dz, '\s')::int[]
from s
```

Comment: Table with 2500 columns smells bad! I like your array solution. Perhaps the destination table structure should be normalized to have 1 value per line or something. Unless the array really does make sense.

Comment: I tried this solution but the array is empty in both s and t tables i updated my question with data structure, any idea?

Comment: @Safariba I will check it later.

Comment: @Safariba Changed the delimiter to `;` and fixed a syntax error in the `\copy` command. Changed the data type of the `localtime` column to `double precision`. Now it works for me with the provided data.

Answer (score 1):

Bit old to reply, just incase for those who still looking.
This can be done using python.

Considering your data in a DataFrame as df.

```
df= df.rename(columns=str.lower)

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql://username:password@localhost:5432/mydatabase')

df.to_sql('table_name', engine)
```

[Read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23103962/how-to-write-dataframe-to-postgres-table#:%7E:text=Create%20a%20table%20in%20your,inserted%20in%20your%20postgres%20table.&text=if%20you%20want%20to%20replace,time%20consuming%20df%20into%20DB.)

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the maximum is 1600 columns, so i devided the csv into two tables of each 1000, I wrote a python code to create dz columns and it works fine:

```
import psycopg2
sqlstring="CREATE TABLE z(id bigint, date date, time time,"
for i in range(1001):
    if(i<1000):
        sqlstring+="dz"+str(i)+ " int,"
    elif i==1000:
        sqlstring+="dz"+str(i)+ " int"        
sqlstring += ");"

connection = psycopg2.connect("dbname='mydb' user='qfsa' host='localhost' password='123' port=5433")
cursor=connection.cursor();
cursor.execute(sqlstring)
connection.commit()
```

now i could import csv into the table.