# How to create a postgres table from a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I'm looking for a way to create a postgres table from a pandas dataframe, and then read the postgre table directly in pgAdmin. 
I've found a way to do that thanks to this link : [How to write DataFrame to postgres table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23103962/how-to-write-dataframe-to-postgres-table) .

The command is :

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql://username:password@host:port/database')
df.to_sql('table_name', engine)
```

However, I don't know what is 'table_name'. Do I have to create a table in my Data Base?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A table with the name you specify will be created if it does not already exist. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

Comment: Ok, the thing is that I have an error : `NameError: name 'bat_prediction_rf' is not defined` . The last lign of my code is `baonotnull_test.to_sql(bat_prediction_rf, engine)` . Maybe it's because of the schema. I explain ; I would like to create a table names 'bat_prediction_rf' in the schema p_baobat itself in the database db. I don't understand why I have this error...

Comment: @Pollux should that be `baonotnull_test.to_sql('bat_prediction_rf', engine)` (note here `'bat_prediction_rf'` is a string) or is `bat_prediction_rf` a variable defined somewhere else in your code?

Comment: You're right, `bat_prediction_rf` isn't defined in my code, I have to write `'bat_prediction_rf'`. Thank you very much it's working! Sorry for disturbing you.

Comment: @Pollux no problem, and I'm happy to know it is working for you now :-)