# Postgresql run psql cmd using python to upload csv file

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, psql

I'm running script in Jupyter notebook to upload csv file into Postgresql table. Jupyter notebook is on server1 and postgresql server is on another server server2.

psql client also installed on Jupyter machine(server1). Able to upload file using below psql command from server1

```
hari@idrtnjdhew1:~/data$ psql -h server2.zzz.com -p 5432 -d db_name -U hari1 -c '\COPY test_upload FROM 'file_name.csv' CSV HEADER'
```

But I have to write scripts in Jupyter notebooks to upload file into postgresql server table.

```
import psycopg2 as pg
import os
import sys

conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host="server2",
    database="db_name",
    user="hari1",
    password="xyz")
        
cursor = conn.cursor()

delete = """Truncate table test_upload"""

cursor.execute(delete)

copy_cmd = """
psql -c "\COPY (test_upload) FROM STDIN  CSV HEADER" < '\home\data\file_name.csv'
"""
cursor.execute(copy_cmd)
```

But above scripts is giving error `SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "psql" LINE : psql -c "\COPY (test_upload) FROM STDIN...`

Is there way to execute psql command using psycopg2

Comment: I'm not sure the sinqle quotes in your copy_cmd are correct.

Comment: typo mistake corrected in stackoverflow

Comment: In general I think a cursor.execute() should take a sql command, not a psql command. To execute psql commands you probably just want to run your psql command as a shell command (with some kind of method in python to invoke a shell command).

Comment: There are some examples here of using sqlalchemy though: [using-sqlalchemy-to-load-csv-file-into-a-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31394998/using-sqlalchemy-to-load-csv-file-into-a-database)

Comment: If all you have is a pandas hammer and this looks like a pandas nail then you can also use a pandas hammer: [how-can-i-load-a-csv-into-a-database-with-sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56165255/how-can-i-load-a-csv-into-a-database-with-sqlalchemy) - see answer from Martin Thoma

Comment: That's a shell command, not an SQL command.  You can use `os.system` or `subprocess.run` to run that script.  Personally, I think it's just about as easy to read the CSV file in Python and do `INSERT` commands.

Comment: See `psycopg2` [copy_from](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from).

Comment: thanks @topsail for sharing post `using sqlalchemy`.  since mine is bulk file, i took 2nd solution from the post. below is working for me 
`with open(csv_file_path, 'r') as f:    
    cmd = 'COPY test_upload(col1, col2, col3) FROM STDIN WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER FALSE)'
    cursor.copy_expert(cmd, f)
    conn.commit()`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver  earlier I tried copy_from() method, but it didn't for work as my file header. couldn't find argument for header=true

Comment: Then you need [copy_expert](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_expert) or get rid of the header line in the file.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver can't rid of header. Anyway,  As mentioned above copy_expert resolved my issue. Thanks

Comment: Actually it easy enough  `csv_file = open('\home\data\file_name.csv')` then `csv_file.readline()` then `copy_from(csv_file)`