# Fastest way to load a very large pandas dataframe to postgresql database

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, dataframe, asyncpg

I am creating a database from three `.csv` files I receive daily. I cleaned them with pandas and now each of them are in a respective pandas dataframe. The largest is about 100,000 by 500 and the others are similar in size. I need the fastest way to upload each dataframe to 3 different tables in `postgresql`. This really needs to be fast because I also have to upload about 10 years worth of data.

I have used `sqlalchemy` and `psycopg2` with `df.to_sql` as well as converting the dataframe to a csv and uploading in batch. Uploading a csv was the fastest but would yield constant type errors and would crash. `sqlalchemy` and `psycopg2` worked perfectly but just take about an hour or more for all three of them to run. Chunksize, fastmany, and multi keywords all yielded about the same speed. I was looking at using asyncpg but I am confused on how to implement it.

Please, any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe a simple export to an sql dump (a file with a large single sql insert expression per file) help. From `<your favourite shell>` you could use `psql` and multiple processors to import such a dump into your database. psql should be the fastest way possible, imho.

Comment: do you mean you have 500 columns?  if that's true, you might think about normalising your data before putting into the database.  PG certainly supports that, but it's a long way from recommended usage

Comment: also just eyeballing the numbers, 100k rows * 4000 days * 4kb (at best, if you've got 500 columns) per row is 1.5TB, means you're probably at the point it's probably worth partitioning the table maybe by year

Comment: This answer to another post helped a great deal [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47984180/5476158)

Comment: @SamManson Yes I have about 500 columns in each file. Unfortunately, all are necessary. But your suggestion about partitioning by year is very helpful and one I had not considered. Thank you!