# Invalid argument(s) 'fast_executemany' when using to_sql()

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pandas-to-sql

I'm trying to speed up to_sql() by using fast_executemany.  But I'm getting an error,

TypeError: Invalid argument(s) 'fast_executemany' sent to create_engine(), using configuration PGDialect_psycopg2/QueuePool/Engine.  Please check that the keyword arguments are appropriate for this combination of components.

I've been referencing this previous question, [Speeding up pandas.DataFrame.to_sql with fast_executemany of pyODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48006551/speeding-up-pandas-dataframe-to-sql-with-fast-executemany-of-pyodbc).

```
database_url = 'postgresql://{user}:{password}@{host}:5432/{database_name}'.format(
    user=user,
    host=host,
    password=password,
    database_name=database_name,
)
engine = create_engine(database_url, echo=False, fast_executemany=True)
df.to_sql('parquet', con=engine,if_exists='replace')
```

This code executes if I remove the fast_executemany argument, but takes pretty long.  I'm using Python 3.7.

Comment: I think fast_executemany is just for Pyodbc driver  https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mssql.html#mssql-pyodbc-fastexecutemany

Comment: You are correct, I'm trying to speed up the upload with to_sql() but this doesn't work.  I think I found the answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23103962/how-to-write-dataframe-to-postgres-table