# Creating a string using for loops in python with optimized time performance

Tags: python, performance, loops, optimization, parallel-processing

I have a pandas data frame called customer_df of length 11k. I am creating a SQL query to insert values of the df to a table customer_details on postgres.

my code right now is

```
insert_string = 'insert into  customer_details (col1,col2,col3,col4) values '
for i in range(len(customer_df)):
    insert_string = insert_string  + ('''('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}'),'''.format(customer_df.iloc[i]['customer'],customer_df.iloc[i]['customerid'],customer_df.iloc[i]['loc'],customer_df.iloc[i]['pin']))

upload_to_postgres(insert_string)
```

this string finally gives me something like

*insert into customer_details (col1,col2,col3,col4)  values ('John',23,'KA',560021),('Ram',67,'AP',642918),(values of cust 3) .... (values of cust 11k)*
which is sent to postgres using the upload_to_postgres.

This process of creating the string takes around 30secs to 1min. Is there any better optimized way to reduce the timings?

Comment: Is there any restriction in using pandas to write it to postgres for you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/23104436/1212401

Comment: no restrictions

Comment: Then you dont need to construct all the SQL yourself, have a look in my link you can just call `df.to_sql` passing it the relevant params for postgres.

Comment: tried doing df.to_sql the insert query got stuck idle in transaction state for a very long time

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas to create and read that df faster
here's a pandas cheat sheet and the library download link
https://pandas.pydata.org/Pandas_Cheat_Sheet.pdf
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/install.html

Comment: OP is using pandas: "I have a pandas data frame". This is not an answer.

Comment: I didn't see where he used that sorry. But if he's already using pandas just use this guide https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html

Comment: The answer space is for *answers* to the question, not for providing links. Please see [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Especially since you've had some lower-quality answers recently.

Answer (score 0):

The multiple insert is not the right way.
At each row you create a transaction, so the best solution is to do a **bulk insert**.
If you can create a file like a CSV and use the bulk action copy, your performance increases of order of magnitude. I've no example here, but i've found [this](https://naysan.ca/2020/05/09/pandas-to-postgresql-using-psycopg2-bulk-insert-performance-benchmark/) article that exlain well the methodology.