# to_sql() alternative to fast_executemany for databases other than SQL Server

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to speed-up the way to write my DataFrame in a SQLite database.
To do so, I'm trying to use Method 4 on this [website](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/speed-up-bulk-inserts-to-sql-db-using-pandas-and-python-61707ae41990).
I also found a more elegant way to change the variable `cursor.fast_executemany = True` thanks to a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48006551/speeding-up-pandas-dataframe-to-sql-with-fast-executemany-of-pyodbc) on Stack Overflow.

The problem is that this error occurs:
`TypeError: Invalid argument(s) 'fast_executemany' sent to create_engine(), using configuration SQLiteDialect_pysqlite/NullPool/Engine.  Please check that the keyword arguments are appropriate for this combination of components.`

I'm using sqlalchemy version 1.3.23 and pandas version 1.14.0.

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine # database connection
from sqlalchemy import event
from IPython.display import display

disk_engine = create_engine('sqlite:///2021_database.db',fast_executemany=True)
data.to_sql('data', disk_engine, if_exists='replace')
```

Here, `data` is my DataFrame. When I run this code without `fast_executemany=True`, it works.

Someone has any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fast_executemany=True` is specific to the `mssql+pyodbc://` dialect. It will not work with other dialects like `sqlite://`. For other databases you would normally use `method="multi"` (or a custom function for PostgreSQL as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55495065/2144390)).

However, SQLite appears to have a limit of 999 parameter values in a single SQL statement so you would also need to use the `chunksize=` argument:

```py
# value to pass to index= argument
use_index = False

# calculate chunksize= , taking into account whether we'll be
# uploading the index
chunk_size = 999 // (len(df.columns) + (1 if use_index else 0))

df.to_sql(
    "table1",
    engine,
    index=use_index,
    if_exists="replace",
    method="multi",
    chunksize=chunk_size,
)
```

#### Edit:

Based on comments below, I tested `df.to_sql()` inserting 1_000_000 rows into a SQLite database on my local hard drive.

`method=None` (the default): 1_000_000 rows written in 53 seconds

`method="multi"` (as above): 1_000_000 rows written in 505 seconds

Apparently Python's `sqlite3` module has some sort of optimization similar to `fast_executemany=True` already built-in, so an `.executemany()` with 1_000_000 rows (`pd.to_sql(…, method=None)`) is about an order of magnitude faster than ~5 thousand `.execute()` calls inserting 199 rows each (`pd.to_sql(…, method="multi")`).

Comment: Thanks. Is there any substitute to `fast_executemany` with `sqlite://`?
I also tried to replace `sqlite://` by `mssql+pyodbc://`, but it doesn't seem to be as simple as that.

Comment: With SQLite you would need to use to_sql's `method="multi"` option.

Comment: Indeed, I tried: when I use it, the code runs but nothing happens. I'm forced to kill the script.

I made a test with few data. Without `multi`, it takes 40s, but when I use `multi`, I can let it during 20 minutes, it's still working and nothing is written in the database.

Comment: You will probably also have to use `chunksize=`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Hi again. Thank you for updated solution. I just tried the solution you proposed. It returns an error: "OperationalError: too many SQL variables". The value of `chunksize` is 45. Any idea?

Comment: The test I made is based on a 1300000 rows × 23 columns table, clearly it's not something huge.

Comment: `999 // 23` is `43`, not `45`

Comment: Your're right, it works. My last question: for this test (1300000 × 23 data), when I use `multi` option, it takes 232 seconds while, w/o this option, it takes 32s. If it's a question of balance between execution time of this option and amount of data, where is the compromise? In other words, how many "data" is necessary to make `multi` option useful?

Comment: If it only takes 32 seconds with `method=None` (the default) and it takes 232 seconds with `method="multi"` then just use the former. The point of using `method="multi"` (and `fast_executemany=True` for that matter) is to reduce the number of round-trips to the database server. SQLite (a file-based database) is a bit different from other (client/server) databases and it could well be that the pandas (Python) cost of building ~30 thousand multi-row INSERT statements is greater than the cost of the SQLite engine processing 1.3 million individual INSERT statements.