# fast_executemany=True is not working in flask

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, flask, mysql-connector

**I have tried three of them below. But nothing works.**

> Error: - TypeError: Invalid argument(s) 'fast_executemany' sent to create_engine(), using configuration MSDialect_pyodbc/QueuePool/Engine.  Please check that the keyword arguments are appropriate for this combination of components.

---

```
engine = create_engine('mysql+pyodbc://{DB}:{Password}@{server}', fast_executemany=True)
engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://{DB}:{Password}@{server}', fast_executemany=True)
engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://{DB}:{Password}@{server}', fast_executemany=True)
```

Comment: seeam like `fast_executemany=True` needs to be either `true` only or `'fast_executemany=True'`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the 'fast_executemany' parameter only works with MSSQL, not MySQL. I was running into the same issue and found more information here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/66339461/21364405 .