# sqlalchemy engine/connection vs psycopg2 connection

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

We currently use a `get_connection` functionality for our postgres via

```py
import psycopg2


def get_db_connection(conn_str: str = '') -> psycopg2._psycopg.connection:
    conn_str = conn_str if conn_str else os.environ.get(PG_CONNECTION_STRING)
    return psycopg2.connect(conn_str)
```

Now that we're working with pandas dataframes, and we want to write them to the DB as new tables, I see in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23104436/3517025) and the [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) that you can use an sqlalchemy engine or connection.

```py
df.to_sql(con=sqlalchemy_cnx, 'table_name')
```

Is there a relationship between a psycopg2 connection and an sqlalchemy connection such that I could create the latter from the former?

Something like

```py
get_pandas_compliant_db_cnx(cnx: psycopg2._psycopg.connection) -> sqlalchemy.engine.Connection:
    # this is what i'm trying to implement to avoid managing both systems
```

Comment: FWIW the SQLA `connection` is lazy and will close itself. Depending on your library setup, you might need only create a single `connection` object somewhere in a config object and just pass that around where it's needed

Comment: Do the df's have a common schema btw or are these free-wheeling uploads and you want dynamic schemas for each table? I have a great distrust of using SQL with a `pandas` wrapper

Comment: The intended use is a common schema - but what is your reason to distrust the `pandas` sql wrapper?